# Instantiate Singleton with Variables

Tags: c#, singleton

I'm using Jon Skeet's great guide on Singletons in C# found here:

[Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)
(Sixth version - using .NET 4's Lazy type)

What I'm trying to do is create a reference class that contains configuration materials used by other classes throughout the program. (settings, themes, etc...)

That reference class has a dependence on a few variables that are provided by a ClientContext object (Scope, TenantID, etc)

For example, there is a settings object that is stored in a database, and needs the TenancyID to pull out the settings for the current scope.

How do I properly use the Singleton pattern, but delay instantiation until a variable is passed to it?

**Addendum**

In Jon's example, it instantiates itself based on a private static class that cannot be fed a variable.

```
private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
    new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
```

How do I feed a GUID representing an TenantID to a private static readonly variable?

Comment: Are you sure a singleton is what you want? If it depends on values from the current client context then once initiated any other requests / clients will get those values instead of their own. Of course if that won't be the case then I guess the first couple of examples are the easiest to do because you can grab all your context stuff in the Instance getter under the lock.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your singleton instance a [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This won't instantiate until you attempt to access it. For more examples, [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Edit: I just realized Jon Skeet even calls this out specifically [in his guide](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy).

Comment: And the art of not reading the question turns out to be quite fun. You just have referenced a link that Op also did...

Comment: But it looks like the instance triggers itself when you call Singleton.Instance, or Singleton.Instance.Property

How do I supply properties to that instantiation that it cannot provide itself?

Comment: You could also make the `.Instance` property private and add a public method such as `GetInstance(...)` and have that method access the `Lazy<T>`. That way your method can supply those properties.